# Apply multiple stencils to a material

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber

I'm building a 2D UI for a WebXR app, where each mesh applies a mask to any children that are outside it's plane. Here's what I have so far:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <script type="module">
      import * as THREE from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.121.0/build/three.module.js";
      import { OrbitControls } from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.121.1/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js";

      const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
      renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
      document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

      const aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
      const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, aspect, 0.1, 1000);
      const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

      const scene = new THREE.Scene();

      camera.position.z = 2;

      const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        depthWrite: false,
        stencilFunc: THREE.AlwaysStencilFunc,
        stencilFail: THREE.ReplaceStencilOp,
        stencilZFail: THREE.ReplaceStencilOp,
        stencilZPass: THREE.ReplaceStencilOp,
        stencilWrite: true
      });

      const parentMaterial = material.clone();
      parentMaterial.color.set("crimson");
      parentMaterial.stencilRef = 1;
      const parent = new THREE.Mesh(
        new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1, 1),
        parentMaterial
      );

      // This child needs to use the parent stencil but also
      // provice a stencil to the grandchild
      const childMaterial = material.clone();
      childMaterial.color.set("lightblue");
      childMaterial.stencilFunc = THREE.EqualStencilFunc;
      childMaterial.stencilFail = THREE.KeepStencilOp;
      childMaterial.stencilZFail = THREE.KeepStencilOp;
      childMaterial.stencilZPass = THREE.KeepStencilOp;
      childMaterial.stencilRef = 1;
      const child = new THREE.Mesh(
        new THREE.PlaneGeometry(0.5, 0.5),
        childMaterial
      );
      child.position.x = 0.5;

      // This grandchild needs to use the child stencil
      const grandchildMaterial = material.clone();
      grandchildMaterial.color.set("white");
      grandchildMaterial.stencilFunc = THREE.EqualStencilFunc;
      grandchildMaterial.stencilFail = THREE.KeepStencilOp;
      grandchildMaterial.stencilZFail = THREE.KeepStencilOp;
      grandchildMaterial.stencilZPass = THREE.KeepStencilOp;
      grandchildMaterial.stencilRef = 1;
      const grandchild = new THREE.Mesh(
        new THREE.PlaneGeometry(0.25, 0.25),
        grandchildMaterial
      );
      grandchild.position.x = -0.25;

      scene.add(parent);
      parent.add(child);
      child.add(grandchild);

      (function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);

        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

        controls.update();

        renderer.render(scene, camera);
      })();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In the code above, I'm able to apply a mask to `child` and `grandchild`. Is there a way to apply multiple stencil masks to the `child`, so that it references the `parent` stencil, but also has it's own stencil that the `grandchild` can reference?